# Problem with class recognition in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

After replacing the TdApi file with a newer version, I began to display it with the extension. Although if I roll back to the old version, it is already displayed normally, without an extension.

After replacing the file, my project stopped referring to this class. Writes "Cannot resolve symbol TdApi".
If I do a rollback, then all links work correctly.
And project build successful.

I can't understand why this happened and how to fix it.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Avb4.png)

Comment: Did you change only file content?

Comment: @y.bedrov Yes. Actually, the solution to the problem has already been found. It turns out it was just necessary to increase the parameter "idea.max.intellisense.filesize" in IDEA. IDEA just didn't see the whole file, that's why there was such an artifact with the processing of this class.

Answer (score -1):

It means that the files exist locally, but are not in the repository, and are not scheduled for addition. With other words the files are not under version control. There is not really a problem since the files can just be added to the VCS if desired.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't quite understand what you mean.
Are you sure that you wanted to write your answer in this topic?